# CartoCSS to MapboxGL

Tags: cartocss, mapbox-gl

I have some old styles in CartoCSS and some I have found online.

However obviously with the update of mapbox studio it uses Mapbox GL styling and the two are different. I can't see a way of importing CartoCSS into mapbox studio.

I have done a little research and have found some CartoCSS to JSON converters. But I'd like to understand the best way of doing this to minimise any transalation errors in the process. Ideally if anyone has tried and tested any methods it would be really useful to underatand the pros and cons related to each method.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?